# Angular spinner async on http request

Tags: angular, observable, loader

I have mi in place an http request spinner that appears if a request is in progress. Except that I get the following error :

```
Error: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'false'. Current value: 'true'.

<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row col-md-12">
    <div class="spinner-style" *ngIf="isLoading | async">
      <mat-spinner spinner-delay="2000"></mat-spinner>
    </div>

    <app-another-comp-table[isLoading]="isLoading | async">
.....
    </app-another-comp-table>
  </div>
</div>
```

My method init in my component :

```
ngOnInit(){
    this.isLoading = this.loaderService.getIsLoading$();

...
}
```

My Loader service :

```
export class LoaderService {
  public isLoading = new BehaviorSubject(false);

  constructor() { }

  getIsLoading$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.isLoading.asObservable();
  }
  
}
```

Comment: You have to show more code where you are using `isLoading`. My guess is that you are executing a code in `AfterViewInit` ...

Comment: I’ve updated my question. I subscribe to loading changes in ngOnInit. This is an observable

Comment: Can you please show the code of getIsLoading$() ?

Comment: I add my LoadService

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error because isLoading changes from false to true.
When you declare isLoading, his default value will be false. The DOM did not have time to process the false value, and it changes to true when your observable end.

RxJS is strictly sequential and subscriptions happen synchronously.

A solution can be to wrap your variable with `setTimeout()` or with `NgZone.run()`.

You can also do this with rxjs using `subscribeOn(async)` operator.

```
import { asyncScheduler } from 'rxjs';
import { observeOn } from 'rxjs/operators';
...
getIsLoading$(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.isLoading.asObservable()
  .pipe(observeOn(asyncScheduler);
}
```

**PS : You should end the name of an observable with $ (isLoading$)**